# Online Excel Web-based Platform

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpmyadmin

I just want to install Excel on my webserver (online excel platform) so that I can connect my database (phpmyadmin) with it. And make some excel files and also export as .pdf

( I just need to make invoices and save it and export it )
( right now i am doing it in excel, and copy and paste the details from the database, but if I have a online excel I can connect /link the database and select the user from the database and make invoice and save it as pdf right?)

Comment: Use php excel package, check some references in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of following php packages...

https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

https://code.google.com/p/php-excel/

If you are looking for web based excel view, then use following jquery package.

http://handsontable.com/

Comment: Thank you very much, But i don't see a example or a demo how it will look like? Will i get a Web Based Excel Platform, if i install this one on my server ? : https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: You will have to code a export tool which would take data from your db and export to excel file using PHPExcel package.

Comment: So that is not a Webbased Excel Platform? I wil not get that interface like excel right?

Comment: Thanks! That is what i looking for, but i can not create and save the file as pdf with handsontable right? Do you have maybe a good solution? Where i will have a web based view, where i can create, save, open a excel file, and also export/save it as PDF ?

Comment: Please open new question for that, and accept my answer as it solved your query.